# Keep 'id' in snappysnippet

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I recently found a google chrome extension tool 'snappysnippet'.
It can export html/css finely except 'id', which will be changed in general name like 'DIV_1'.

Somehow i want to keep the 'id's, though, how can i do that?
('class' can be preserved by turning off 'Format and clean up HTML' option)
Or are there any other alternative tools?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/kdzwinel/SnappySnippet) and is under the GPL. Download it and modify it to do what you want.  The last change to the code was a year ago, so the author may not be that responsive.